# iPhone 4 keeps losing contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

My iPhone 4 keeps losing contacts under various conditions: first [after an app crash followed by a manual reboot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100936); all the other times after the battery becomes empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What proved helpful in my situation was replacing the battery (which was nearly 3 years old) with a new one. Since then I haven't reached a zero battery in several weeks, but after all it stopped the lost contacts problem from reappearing since the replacement.